# How to disable copy on a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jlabel

First of all I have to say that I never worked on java application.

I've been asked to prevent the possibility the user copy (ctrl+c or right click of the mouse) the content of JTable/JLabel (I didn't developed this java application).

I can't disable JTable or JLabel since the user must be allowed to edit them. I just need to disable the copy function on JLabel and/or JLabel.

What's the easiest way?
I read some posts on the internet but I didn't understand much since I never worked on Java application.

Thank you

Comment: I would be interested in why you want to do that in the first place? In doubt the user can make a screenshot or type it up manually anyway.

Comment: I know, it is a weird user request!!!! I explain it but the user want it!

Comment: Can you link the posts you read. The link I previously posted seems to be outdated, so I removed it again. (at least the javadoc didn't mentioned any of these method anymore)

Comment: You will need to call [setTransferHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setTransferHandler%28javax.swing.TransferHandler%29) on the JTable.  In my opinion, this is not a task someone new to Java should be undertaking.

Comment: @VGR actually I already used setTransferHandler and it work if try to to use ctrl+c.
The problem is that If I double click on a cell, and the cursor appears, I'm still able to to do ctrl+c.

Comment: @second this is the link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/TransferHandler.html#exportToClipboard-javax.swing.JComponent-java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard-int-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the "Ctrl+C" Key Binding on the JTable by using:

```
InputMap im = table.getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control C"), "none");
```

Comment: `control C` is right for Windows and Linux.  To make sure it works on a Mac as well, use `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMaskEx())`.

Answer (score 1):

You can override this behavior by calling [setTransferHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setTransferHandler%28javax.swing.TransferHandler%29) on the JTable, which you seem to already understand.

When a cell is being edited, the [CellEditor for the column’s class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTable.html#setDefaultEditor%28java.lang.Class,javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor%29) is active.  To prevent copying during a cell edit:

- Create a new JTextField
- Call that JTextField’s setTransferHandler method
- [Create a new DefaultCellEditor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/DefaultCellEditor.html#%3Cinit%3E%28javax.swing.JTextField%29) with that JTextField
- Install that cell editor on your JTable:

  ```
  TransferHandler copyDisabledHandler = new TransferHandler() {
      @Override
      public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
          return NONE;
      }
  };

  JTextField editorField = new JTextField();
  editorField.setTransferHandler(copyDisabledHandler);

  TableCellEditor uncopyableEditor = new DefaultCellEditor(editorField);

  table.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, uncopyableEditor);
  ```

Depending on the values returned by your TableModel’s [getColumnClass method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#getColumnClass%28int%29), you may need to pass a class other than `Object.class` to setDefaultEditor, such as `String.class` or `Integer.class`.